# Alexa HTTPS endpoint - don't get any request

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I was successfully set the Alexa Build steps(checklist) on Alexa Developer Console.

[image]

As endpoint I want to use my own remote server(nodeJS, not AWS lambda), I found the next example and trying to use it now:
https://github.com/Glogo/alexa-skill-sample-nodejs-express

By using `POSTMAN` I can send a JSON with `intent` to my nodeJS server and successfully get a response.

But once I try to test the flow through Alexa Test Simulator (Test tab in Alexa Developer Console) I don't get any response... On the server side, I can't see any request that comes from Alexa.

[image]

I wonder, what is the problem in this case? 
Maybe I didn't understand how it should work... I expect to receive a JSON request from Alexa and to output a response.

It's important to mention that I didn't set any properties "Distribution" and "Certification" tabs. As I understand, for testing it's not necessary.

Comment: What is your connection to the alexa service? How is localhost reachable to the alexa service? are you utilizing something like ngrok to provide availability for the service to interact with you?

Comment: I have a remote server on DigitalOcean which is accessible to HTTP requests (tested with POSTMAN), so it's not a localhost server. I don't use any tunnel/proxy service because there is no reason to do that.

Of course, I set the HTTPS as Alexa requires.

Comment: From the screenshot of test simulator, you didn't invoke/launch your skill.  Once you launch your skill, request JSON will be generated. Then check whether your nodejs server can handle that request.

Comment: @CicilThomas, Thank you for your response!
I think you right, it feels like the setup process isn't finished yet. Unfortunately, I can't understand what is missing there, I get no errors or any "guide notifications" from Alexa...

Can you please explain how should I "launch" the skill? I covered all the "Build" process - entered my custom "Intents" and built the model successfully. I was sure this is enough to start using the service.

Comment: Just like how you invoke a skill through an Echo device, use "open <skill invocation name>"

Comment: Show us the response you are sending from there

Comment: and calling/typing the invocation name of your skill. and please show us the endpoint you have submitted in alexa

Comment: Thank you @CicilThomas, you were absolutely right! :D
I didn't get any feedback because the skill/app was not running :D

Not it works perfectly! Thanks! Please post your response as "answer", so I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: @Exterminator, thank you for your help and attention, looks like we have solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot of test simulator, you didn't invoke/launch your skill. Once you launch your skill, a request JSON will be generated by which you can check whether your nodejs server can handle that request.

You can invoke your skill from Test Simulator by:

```
open, <skill invocation name>
```

This will trigger a `LaunchRequest`

You can directly trigger an intent of your skill by,

```
ask <skill invocation name> <a sample intent utterance>
```

This will trigger an `IntentRequest` with the mapped intent

For different invocation phrases, check [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html).

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open your skill, because the simulator won't open it for you. You can do this by typing/saying

```
open/start/launch <invocation name>
```

To trigger one of your intent use

```
ask/tell <invocation name> <a sample utterance for your intent>
```